# Decorator pattern wasting memory

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inheritance, polymorphism, decorator

I have this base class having the following interface:

```
abstract class Base
{
  abstract public object Val
  {
    get;
  }
}
```

For any derived classes, `Val`'s value **must** be specified at object creation time.
The question is: How can I **make** a derived class do this (hopefully at compile time)?
I tried adding a constructor:

```
abstract class Base
{
  public Base(object value)
  {
    val = value;
  }

  private object val;

  ...
}
```

But as you can see then I had to declare a private field to store value in it (because Value is read-only).
The problem arises because I want to add some kind of effect to derived classes using the Decorator/Wrapper pattern introduced in GoF Design Patterns. But because I have declared the field inside Base class, the decorators keep saving a copy of the same data and I end up wasting memory.

Comment: A decorator is an object holding another object so you obviously need memory for two objects. That's exactly the memory required for your solution. If that's not fine for you, you are probably misusing or misunderstanding the decorator pattern. What problem  do you want to solve exactly?

Comment: If I define only properties (and not fields) in my Base class then the decorator won't actually have to store any other copies of Base members.

Comment: The decorator does not store any copies of base members. It just stores a reference to the decorated object!?

Comment: It also has to inherit from Base class to have the same interface. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Has your application ever actually run out of memory? Many applications don't need to worry about optimizing for that.

Comment: @TrueWill, No but it still matters. I'm aware of it, and I hate to keep unnecessary copies of data.

Comment: It's a reference. Think "pointer." Unless you are working under major memory constraints, don't worry about it. Your time is worth more.

Comment: @TrueWill, That's true. But I think it's worth learning to do things right. If this was a task given to me I'd probably leave it be and get to do the more important stuff, but since I'm still learning I think I should make sure I'm doing it the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
abstract class Base 
{
    public Base(object val)
    {
        this.Val = val;
    }

    public object Val { get; private set; }
}
```

That way, your derived class doesn't need its own field:

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived(object val) : base(val) { }
}
```

Comment: @AtoMerZ note that this still has a field in the base-class; simply - the compiler is hiding it from us. Automatically implemented properties have a compiler-generated backing field.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a decorator, then don't have a field:

```
public override object Val {
    // add any decoration effects here if needed
    get { return tail.Val; }
}
```

Where `tail` is the thing you are decorating.

---

However, it sounds like you mean inheritance (not decoration) - if so:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    protected BaseClass(object val) {...}
}
class ConcreteType : BaseClass {
    public ConcreteType(object val)
        : base(val) { }
}
```

Here the base class could even handle the storage etc.

Comment: Maybe I don't quite get it. The Base class has a field and since the decorator inherits Base class so does the decorator.  I can override `Val` property but that field remains in memory.

Comment: @AtoMerZ I'm confused... if you don't want the base to have a field, then don't have a field... let the derived class worry about it. If the base doesn't have the field, it also doesn't need the constructor - just have a `public abstract object Value {get;}` and you're done...

Comment: As I said in the question, Derived classes **MUST** initialize `val`. So I had to provide the base class with a constructor to initialize `val`. And this meant I needed to allocate memory for the property (since I had forgotten about private set which was the solution).

Comment: It seems you are confusing Decorator with Proxy

Comment: @ivowiblo no, I don't think do. Decorator **is** an object-wrapping pattern. What makes you think I have confused it?

Comment: Mhhh... after a further reading I was mistaken. One solution to your problem will be to make your decorators implement a common interface with your classes but not extend the class itself. Or put al the logic related to that field in another "decorator-tree"