# Cannot override property's protected set

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, protected

I have the following base class:

```
abstract class Base
{
 public abstract object Var
 {
  get;
  protected set;
 }
}
```

And this derived class:

```
class Derived : Base
{
 public override object Var
 {
  get {//code here
  }
  set {//code here -- I get error here!
  }
 }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Cannot change access modifier when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'Var'

I tried adding a `protected` and `private` keywords before set but it didn't help. How do I fix this?

**UPDATE:**
The base class **must** make sure that subclasses provide a value for `Var` at creation time. So I need to have the setter declared in Base class.
Alternatively, I could declare a private member variable to do this and remove the setter, but that is not an option as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8466706/279982).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the `set` in your derived class has `public` visiblity—since you didn't specify `protected` explicitly.  Since this property's set has protected visibility in your base class, you're getting the error

> cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member

You can fix it by giving the set protected visibility in your derived class:

```
class Derived : Base {
    public override object Var {
        get { return null; }
        protected set { // <------ added protected here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my god! Stupid VS! As I said in my post I had tried this and it did not help. I retried when you mentioned it, it still didn't work, I looked at your answer again, recompiled, and it's gone! So what do I do now? should I accept your answer or should I remove my post?

Comment: @AtoMerZ - I would accept the best answer and move on.  Since the question has upvoted answers, you'll need a mod to remove it.  Not worth the trouble for anyone.